# How to access COWIN APIs?

Tags: api, flutter, rest, public-key

I want to access these APIs from [cowin.gov.in](https://cowin.gov.in)

This API is for getting the vaccination certificate -

https://ndh.digitallocker.gov.in/public/marketplace/api/cowin/cowincert

But when I access this using mobile number and a beneficiary ID , I get **unauthorized access**.

It requires to generate token and require following this from this site  - https://openapi.aarogyasetu.gov.in/profile

I am integrating this to my Flutter App how can I get the following

1. Your Public Key (Callback data will be signed using this)
2. Callback URL

I am an individual using this API but it needs some company info too. What should I do?

[Check this image for more details of registration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XM4I5.png)

Comment: Were you able to figure out what all data you have to fill in there?

Comment: @ritwikshanker nope

Comment: any progress as to how to get api key for publicly open endpoints?

Comment: @Speedy11 I mailed ```openapi.aarogyasetu@gov.in``` but this is what they replied  - 
For accessing CoWIN APIs, please contact CoWIN API development and support team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can now raise your issues on https://github.com/cowinapi/developer.cowin

This is official github repository of **COWIN**

You can check all the open issues as well the closed issues for clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the website **https://openapi.aarogyasetu.gov.in/** and got the contact details
**openapi.aarogyasetu@gov.in**. Please try to send a mail to this id and lets see what they are going to respond. I am not sure whether individuals can get access to those API's since they are asking a lot of information about company/organization.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the image below, We might need to contact the Ministry of Health and Family Welfare, Government of India to get access to the protected APIs.

[image: Screenshot from Official Website Here]

Comment: not talking about protected API's. the question is how to get api key for publicly open endpoints

Comment: @Speedy11 Yes same problem here

Comment: @Speedy11 There are public APIs there whichh u can access without keys. For the API Key, u can email them as well.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an api key for accessing the public api end points

Answer (score 0):

mention general user agent like this {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36 Edg/90.0.818.56"} to avoid getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

Co-WIN Public APIs allow any third-party application to access certain un-restricted information, that can be shared with its users. This is limited only to read access in Co-WIN. The appointment availability data is cached and may be up to 5 minutes old. Further, these APIs are subject to a rate limit of 100 API calls per 5 minutes per IP.
Swager API documentation official resource
https://apisetu.gov.in/public/api/cowin/cowin-public-v2

Answer (score -3):

```
header = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36',
        'origin': 'https://selfregistration.cowin.gov.in/',
        'referer': 'https://selfregistration.cowin.gov.in/'
    }
```

**also needs**

```
data = {"mobile": mobile,
                "secret": "U2FsdGVkX1+z/4Nr9nta+2DrVJSv7KS6VoQUSQ1ZXYDx/CJUkWxFYG6P3iM/VW+6jLQ9RDQVzp/RcZ8kbT41xw=="
        }
```

***source***
https://github.com/pallupz/covid-vaccine-booking/

Comment: this is actually right but the problem is that this secret key should keep on changing according to browser